# Keep tree stucture in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following document:

```
<Doc>
    <If cond="c">
       <Expr>Expr1</Expr>
    </If>
    <Expr>Expr2</Expr>
</Doc>
```

Which should create an output like this:

```
If c { Expr1 } Expr2
```

However, in my case it creates:

```
Expr1 If c { Expr1 } Expr2
```

I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="Doc">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="If">
      <xsl:text>if </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@cond"/><xsl:text> {</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Expr"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Expr">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The idea is that Expr Elements are to be transformed in their right position. Nested ifs could be possible. The problem I have is that an Expr-Element is duplicated.

Comment: The easy solution was just to remove the apply-templates from the If and to add the } otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="If">
     if <xsl:value-of select="@cond"/> <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="If/Expr">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' { ', ., ' }')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Expr">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Doc>
    <If cond="c">
        <Expr>Expr1</Expr>
    </If>
    <Expr>Expr2</Expr>
</Doc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
 if c { Expr1 } Expr2
```

**Do note**:

If you simplify your transformation just to this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="If">
          <xsl:text>if </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@cond"/><xsl:text> {</xsl:text>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Expr"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Expr">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**then a correct result is produced**:

```
if c {Expr1}
Expr2
```

Answer (score -1):

It's always quite difficult to understand exactly what behaviour people are asking for from stylesheets, but what I think you're asking is 'how do I make sure that only `Expr` elements under `If` elements get transformed inside parentheses?'

Try modifying `template match="Expr"` to `template match="If/Expr"` - this tells the transformation engines that only Exprs living under Ifs should be matched.